# How to put variable inside ajax response onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In js after loop i am creating the variable like:

```
var type ='sim';
var id   = 'add_dyno_crew_'+itemsn.id;
var ids  = 'addcrew_sub_'+itemsn.id;
```

In html onclick function where i want to use this value as a parameter is given below :

```
html+='<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 padding_left_right_none add_crew_btn"><p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="strt_txt" onclick="dash_add_aircrew('+type+','+id+','+ids+');">+ Add Aircrew</a></p></div>';
```

but when i am using this variable inside the onclick it giving me the error like not defined and code is not working can anyone one pls explain it to me ???

Comment: You need to wrap the values in quotes within the output as they are strings. Better still, put them in `data` attributes and get rid of the inline event handler.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is very hard to tell exactly what you are asking. Please post a [Mnimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can identify the problem.

Comment: How do you get `itemsn.id` outside `loops`

Answer (score 0):

You missed quotes

```
html+='<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 padding_left_right_none add_crew_btn"><p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="strt_txt" onclick="dash_add_aircrew(\''+type+'\',\''+id+'\',\''+ids+'\');">+ Add Aircrew</a></p></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not concatenate variable with quotes instead use template litrel like this

```
html+=`<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 padding_left_right_none add_crew_btn"><p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="strt_txt" onclick="dash_add_aircrew(${type},${id},${ids});">+ Add Aircrew</a></p></div>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML string you are generating by string concatenation is not valid. I will suggest you to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is more cleaner:

```js
var type ='sim';
var id   = 'add_dyno_crew_'+11;
var ids  = 'addcrew_sub_'+11; 

var html = '';
html+=`<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 padding_left_right_none add_crew_btn"><p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="strt_txt" onclick="dash_add_aircrew('${type}','${id}','${ids}');">+ Add Aircrew</a></p></div>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

function dash_add_aircrew(t, id1, id2){
  console.log(t + '::' + id1 + '::' + id2)
}
```